# Plotting principal components of rasterstack in R

Tags: r, time-series, raster, pca

I'm trying to reproduce Figure 1 from [here](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/1993journal/aug/1993_aug_1307-1312.pdf), which is labelled as "Standardized Principal Component lmages 1 through 8 derived from monthly NDV; data, January 1986 to December 1988".

I'm using `principal` from   `psych` package. Here's an example where I have a rasterstack, values and each coordinate. Suppose each raster represents a variable during a year.

```
library(psych) 
library(raster)

r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4<- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3))
values(r4) <- runif(ncell(r4))
x <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4)

extract.value.from.raster.stack<-extract(x,1:ncell(x))
coord<-xyFromCell(x,1:ncell(x))
lon<-coord[1,]
lat<-coord[2,]

pcaan<-t(extract.value.from.raster.stack)
pca3<-principal(pcaan,nfactor=5,rotate="none")
```

After doing the PCA analysis, how can I obtain a similar plot like the paper with correlations?

Comment: Hi! I think that first of all you ought to create a dataset with individuals and loadings. Something like this `cbind(coord,pca3$loadings[1:nrow(pca3$loadings),])
`. I've used the coordinates you giveth, but I think you want areas maybe.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. For the first moment, I would like to work only with points, not area :). So each pixel of the raster has a time series of 4 observations and I would like to apply PCA on these time series.

Comment: So your task is to bind the pixel to the pca loadings, plot the pixels with, as colors, the correlations with the various principal components, and each components has a different plot, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!